# How to apply lasso regression through cellfun in matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array, lasso-regression

I have 2 sets (X and Y) of `9x714` cell arrays where inside the cells consist of various dimension of matrices and empty ones. Cell array `X` and `Y` are symmetrical for matrix dimensions. I would like to use `cellfun` to apply `lasso` regression.

```
[B FitInfo] = cellfun(lasso(X, Y,'CV',4,'Alpha',1));
```

The response received from `Matlab`:

> "Error using lasso (line 221). The parameter 'X' must be a real-valued 2D matrix."

All of the matrices inside the cell are real-values. The above function works when run individually by specifying the cell location, for example:

```
[B FitInfo] = lasso(X{9, 1}, Y{9, 1},'CV',4,'Alpha',1));
```

**Note: the above function is run in single, not using loops.**

Please advise. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your call to `cellfun` has only one parameter. According to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), it takes at least two: the function and the cell array(s) to iterate over.

Comment: Would you please provide some examples. Thank you and much appreciated.